# Create a new Windows Log on Event Viewer

Tags: c#, logging, event-viewer

I need to create a new windows log. I mean this:

[image]

I wrote the following line of code:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("My Application Name", "My Custom Log");
```

It seems it has worked infact this line of code return TRUE

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("My Custom Log");
```

Even if I try to write in that log, everything works:

```
EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
myLog.Source = "My Custom Log";
myLog.WriteEntry("Writing to event log.");
```

But for some reason I still do not see my custom log... I also restarted the pc... What's wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You can find your "My Custom Log" in "Registri applicazioni e servizi"

Comment: oooohhh yes!!! Why? I do not want it there!

Comment: You can only create new eventsource there and not in "Registri di Windows"

Answer (score 2):

Application logs always appear under Applications and services (*Registri applicazioni e servizi*).

Note that in order to write to that location, you need to specify both the source and log names properly when initializing the logger:

```
var myLog = new EventLog(logName: "My Custom Log",
    machineName: ".", source: "My Application Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use EventLogTraceListener Class to create a listener in you **App.config** file.

```
> <system.diagnostics>   <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
>     <listeners>
>       <add name="myListener"
>         type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"
>         initializeData="TraceListenerLog" />
>     </listeners>   </trace> </system.diagnostics>
```

[image]

Then go back to you main **Program.cs** file and create a simple output for windows log.

> ```
> using System.Diagnostics;
>
> namespace ConsoleApplication1
> {
>     class Program
>     {
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             Trace.WriteLine("Test output");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Run the application and go to your event log to check if the Windows log has been created.
[image]

For more details check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogtracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396